# Is there a way to force destroy a machine?

Tags: juju

I've got a unit that is stuck in pending mode, how can I forcefully destroy it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `juju remove-machine --force` command to force this:

> Machines that are responsible for the environment cannot be removed. Machines
>   running units or containers can only be removed with the --force flag; doing
>   so will also remove all those units and containers without giving them any
>   opportunity to shut down cleanly.

Examples:

Remove machine number 5 which has no running units or containers:

```
juju remove-machine 5
```

Remove machine 6 and any running units or containers

```
juju remove-machine 6 --force
```

Source:

- `juju help remove-machine`